# pandas calculate difference based on indicators grouped by a column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, difference

Here is my question. I don't know how to describe it, so I will just give an example.

```
a b k
0 0 0
0 1 1
0 2 0
0 3 0
0 4 1
0 5 0
1 0 0
1 1 1
1 2 0
1 3 1
1 4 0
```

Here, "a" is user id, "b" is time, and "k" is a binary indicator flag. "b" is consecutive for sure.
What I want to get is this:

```
a b k diff_b
0 0 0 nan
0 1 1 nan
0 2 0 1
0 3 0 2
0 4 1 3
0 5 0 1
1 0 0 nan
1 1 1 nan
1 2 0 1
1 3 1 2
1 4 0 1
```

So, diff_b is a time difference variable. It shows the duration between the current time point and the last time point with an action. If there is never an action before, it returns nan. This diff_b is grouped by a. For each user, this diff_b is calculated independently.

Can anyone revise my title? I don't know how to describe it in english. So complex...

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC

```
df['New']=df.b.loc[df.k==1]# get all value b when k equal to 1
df.New=df.groupby('a').New.apply(lambda x : x.ffill().shift()) # fillna by froward method , then we need shift.
df.b-df['New']# yield 
Out[260]: 
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     1.0
3     2.0
4     3.0
5     1.0
6     NaN
7     NaN
8     1.0
9     2.0
10    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: What if i have duplicated rows? Like I have another variable c and for each c, the table looks like the one i provide above. But when you take all records for all c, then there is duplicate rows, like both a = 0,1,2,3,4 and b = 0,1,1,2,3,4. How could i solve this problem?

Comment: @Eleanor I suggest you open another question , and add this new condition

Comment: Ok i just post another question and thank you for the solution. Works very well.

Answer (score 0):

create partitions of the data of rows after `k == 1` up to the next `k == 1` using cumsum, and shift, for each group of `a`

```
parts = df.groupby('a').k.apply(lambda x: x.shift().cumsum())
```

group by the `df.a` & `parts` and calculate the difference between `b` & `b.min()` within each group

```
vals = df.groupby([df.a, parts]).b.apply(lambda x: x-x.min()+1)
```

set values to null when part == 0 & assign back to the dataframe

```
df['diff_b'] = np.select([parts!=0], [vals], np.nan)
```

outputs:

```
    a  b  k  diff_b
0   0  0  0     NaN
1   0  1  1     NaN
2   0  2  0     1.0
3   0  3  0     2.0
4   0  4  1     3.0
5   0  5  0     1.0
6   1  0  0     NaN
7   1  1  1     NaN
8   1  2  0     1.0
9   1  3  1     2.0
10  1  4  0     1.0
```